# How do you force a makefile to rebuild a target?

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a makefile that builds and then calls another makefile. Since this makefile calls more makefiles that does the work it doesn't really change. Thus it keeps thinking the project is built and up to date.

```
dnetdev11 ~ # make
make: `release' is up to date.
```

How do I force the makefile to rebuild the target?

```
clean = $(MAKE) -f ~/xxx/xxx_compile.workspace.mak clean


build = svn up ~/xxx                                                       \
        $(clean)                                                                \
        ~/cbp2mak/cbp2mak -C ~/xxx ~/xxx/xxx_compile.workspace        \
        $(MAKE) -f ~/xxx/xxx_compile.workspace.mak $(1)                    \


release:
        $(build )

debug:
        $(build DEBUG=1)

clean:
        $(clean)

install:
        cp ~/xxx/source/xxx_utility/release/xxx_util /usr/local/bin
        cp ~/xxx/source/xxx_utility/release/xxxcore.so /usr/local/lib
```

Note: Names removed to protect the innocent

Final Fixed version:

```
clean = $(MAKE) -f xxx_compile.workspace.mak clean;


build = svn up;                                         \
        $(clean)                                        \
        ./cbp2mak/cbp2mak -C . xxx_compile.workspace;   \
        $(MAKE) -f xxx_compile.workspace.mak    $(1);   \


.PHONY: release debug clean install

release:
        $(call build,)

debug:
        $(call build,DEBUG=1)

clean:
        $(clean)

install:
        cp ./source/xxx_utillity/release/xxx_util /usr/bin
        cp ./dlls/Release/xxxcore.so /usr/lib
```

Comment: Lodle, since this is a frequently visited question, would you like to edit the question to be more modern? (It looks like `.PHONY` was not your only problem, and you're not really supposed to edit the solution into the question, or at least not anymore.)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could declare one or more of your targets to be [phony](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html).

> A phony target is one that is not really the name of a file; rather it
>   is just a name for a recipe to be executed when you make an explicit
>   request. There are two reasons to use a phony target: to avoid a
>   conflict with a file of the same name, and to improve performance.
>
> ...
>
> A phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real target file; if
>   it is, its recipe will be run every time make goes to update that
>   file. As long as a phony target is never a prerequisite of a real
>   target, the phony target recipe will be executed only when the phony
>   target is a specified goal

Comment: This answer, while it is "accepted" and highly "upvoted" is really off-the-mark. First, it says "declare targets to be phony" but then it says "phony target is not really the name of a file". Well, if your target is a file, that is then a contradiction in the answer.  Second, it says "phony target should not be a prerequisite of a real" - well, what if it is? The original question, did not specify if it is or it is not.  The correct answer, is, _not_ to declare _your_ targets to be phony, but rather, declare an additional phony target, and then, depend the targets you want rebuilt, on that.

Comment: @MarkGaleck. When the answer states that "A phony target is one that is not really the name of a file" it is quoting directly from the gcc make manual. It is perfectly correct.

Comment: "Target" is a Make term that refers to the text to the left of a colon `:`, not just the end result that you want created (e.g. your binary file). In the question, `release`, `debug`, `clean`, and `install` are the Make targets, not `xxx_util` or `xxxcore.so` or anything else.

Comment: How did this get 51 downvotes?! If you read the OP's question carefully it seems possible, or even likely, that `make release`  actually creates a directory named `release`. This means that the output 'release is up to date' is exactly what you'd expect, and the correct answer *is* to declare 'release' as .PHONY. The reason is that you just want to run the 'release' recipe, irrespective of whether or not a 'release' file or directory actually exists. This is precisely what .PHONY is for.

Comment: As the `release` target is calling other targets in other Makefiles to do the real work, using `.PHONY` to leave the incremental build check to those Makefiles makes perfect sense given the OP question. I had the exact same situation and this answer was just perfect for my problem.

Comment: For the specific problem I've just encountered, this was the best solution.

Answer (score 878):

The `-B` switch to make, whose long form is `--always-make`, tells `make` to disregard timestamps and make the specified targets. This may defeat the purpose of using make, but it may be what you need.

Comment: @MarkKCowan I completely agree! This options is exactly what I was looking for, not some workaround hack as Dave suggests.

Comment: The caveat with this approach is , that it just builds tooo many things.
Specifically with autotools, I saw it rerunning  configure .. I wish a LD_PRELOAD based solution can be build !!

Comment: yes, and it can even rewrite files you didn't want to! such as global system libraries that appear in the dependencies and get rebuilt and overwritten...

Comment: CAVEAT: This will do what it says (LOL): rebuild your target from scratch ignoring all timesamps. So if you just want to rebuild the very last step of a long chain (e.g., for testing a new part of a workflow), then a temporary `.PHONY` might be more practical.

Answer (score 26):

One trick that used to be documented in a Sun manual for `make` is to use a (non-existent) target '.FORCE'.  You could do this by creating a file, force.mk, that contains:

```
.FORCE:
$(FORCE_DEPS): .FORCE
```

Then, assuming your existing makefile is called `makefile`, you could run:

```
make FORCE_DEPS=release -f force.mk -f makefile release
```

Since `.FORCE` does not exist, anything that depends on it will be out of date and rebuilt.

All this will work with any version of `make`; on Linux, you have GNU Make and can therefore use the .PHONY target as discussed.

It is also worth considering why `make` considers release to be up to date.  This could be because you have a `touch release` command in amongst the commands executed; it could be because there is a file or directory called 'release' that exists and has no dependencies and so is up to date.  Then there's the actual reason...

Answer (score 21):

Someone else suggested .PHONY which is definitely correct. .PHONY should be used for any rule for which a date comparison between the input and the output is invalid. Since you don't have any targets of the form `output: input` you should use .PHONY for ALL of them!

All that said, you probably should define some variables at the top of your makefile for the various filenames, and define real make rules that have both input and output sections so you can use the benefits of make, namely that you'll only actually compile things that are necessary to copmile!

Edit: added example. Untested, but this is how you do .PHONY

```
.PHONY: clean    
clean:
    $(clean)
```

Comment: Well if you could show me an example it would be nice. Atm im just hacking it up trying to get the dam thing to work :P

Comment: The location of the `.PHONY` target does not matter. It can be anywhere in the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 11):

`make clean` deletes all the already compiled object files.

Answer (score 7):

If I recall correctly, 'make' uses timestamps (file modification time) to determine whether or not a target is up to date. A common way to force a re-build is to update that timestamp, using the 'touch' command. You could try invoking 'touch' in your makefile to update the timestamp of one of the targets (perhaps one of those sub-makefiles), which might force Make to execute that command.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this and it worked for me

add these lines to Makefile

```
clean:
    rm *.o output

new: clean
    $(MAKE)     #use variable $(MAKE) instead of make to get recursive make calls
```

save and now call

```
make new
```

and it will recompile everything again

What happened?

1) 'new' calls clean. 
'clean' do 'rm' which removes all object files that have the extension of '.o'.

2) 'new' calls 'make'. 
'make' see that there is no '.o' files, so it creates all the '.o' again. then the linker links all of the .o file int one executable output

Good luck

Comment: In recipe for `new` better use `$(MAKE)` than `make`

Answer (score 6):

This simple technique will allow the makefile to function normally when forcing is not desired. Create a new target called **force** at the end of your **makefile**. The **force** target will touch a file that your default target depends on. In the example below, I have added **touch myprogram.cpp**. I also added a recursive call to **make**. This will cause the default target to get made every time you type **make force**.

```
yourProgram: yourProgram.cpp
       g++ -o yourProgram yourProgram.cpp 

force:
       touch yourProgram.cpp
       make
```

Comment: You should never use `make` inside a Makefile. Use `$(MAKE)` instead.

Answer (score 6):

As abernier pointed out, there is a recommended solution in the GNU make manual, which uses a 'fake' target to force rebuilding of a target:

```
clean: FORCE
        rm $(objects)
FORCE: ;
```

This will run clean, regardless of any other dependencies.

I added the semicolon to the solution from the manual, otherwise an empty line is required.

Comment: I don't see any need for an empty line here.  I could have imagined a newline being required, but I tested it out, and not even that is the case.  That colon (after `FORCE` on the last line) can be the last character in the file, and this still works.  Perhaps in your test environment you had something else following this that required the semicolon?

Answer (score 2):

As per Miller's [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/) you should avoid calling `$(MAKE)`!  In the case you show, it's harmless, because this isn't really a makefile, just a wrapper script, that might just as well have been written in Shell.  But you say you continue like that at deeper recursion levels, so you've probably encountered the problems shown in that eye-opening essay.

Of course with GNU make it's cumbersome to avoid.  And even though they are aware of this problem, it's their documented way of doing things.

OTOH, [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) was created as a solution for this problem.  You can write your makefiles on a per directory level, yet they all get drawn together into a full view of your project.

But legacy makefiles are written recursively.  So there's a workaround where `$(MAKE)` does nothing but channel the subrequests back to the main makepp process.  Only if you do redundant or, worse, contradictory things between your submakes, you must request `--traditional-recursive-make` (which of course breaks this advantage of makepp).  I don't know your other makefiles, but if they're cleanly written, with makepp necessary rebuilds should happen automatically, without the need for any hacks suggested here by others.

Comment: Did not answer question: tangent to main point and should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough.  With [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/) this whole wrapper makefile is not needed.  By knowing the exact dependencies (all of them, not just what's listed after the `:`) it will always rebuild when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to preserve any of the outputs you already successfully compiled

```
nmake /A
```

rebuilds all

Answer (score 1):

It was already mentioned, but thought I could add to using `touch`

If you `touch` all the source files to be compiled, the `touch` command changes the timestamps of a file to the system time the `touch` command was executed.

The source file timstamp is what `make` uses to "know" a file has changed, and needs to be re-compiled

For example: If the project was a c++ project, then do `touch *.cpp`, then run `make` again, and make should recompile the entire project.

Answer (score 0):

It actually depends on what the target is. If it is a phony target (i.e. the target is NOT related to a file) you should declare it as .PHONY.

If however the target is not a phony target but you just want to rebuild it for some reason (an example is when you use the __TIME__ preprocessing macro), you should use the FORCE scheme described in answers here.

Answer (score -1):

On my Linux system (Centos 6.2), there is a significant difference between declaring the target .PHONY and creating a fake dependency on FORCE, when the rule actually does create a file matching the target.  When the file must be regenerated every time, it required both
the fake dependency FORCE on the file, and .PHONY for the fake dependency.

wrong:

```
date > $@
```

right:

```
FORCE
    date > $@
FORCE:
    .PHONY: FORCE
```