# gmake rule for a header file which is created by the makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I properly write gmake rule for a header file which is generated by the make itself?

Suppose, that I can pass do `make BUILDTYPE=1` and buildtype.h will be created and populated with

```
#define BUILDTYPE 1
```

Makefile will simply do something like this:

```
buildtype.h:
    echo #define BUILDTYPE 1 > TMPFILE
    //pseudo code:
    if(TMPFILE != buildtype.h)
        cat TMPFILE > buildtype.h
```

I need to ensure that this process won't be repeated 1000 times for each cpp file and I want to ensure that this process will be done at least once

What I want to ensure is that this rule runs always and only once. That is, even if buidtype.h exist it still has to be run. I have automatic dependency tracking and it should trigger this rule only once when make runs.

That is, if I run make BUILDTYPE=2 and there is nothing to do, it still has to run that rule for buildtype.h and if buildtype.h will updated by the rule it should recompile all files.

Is something like that possible with gmake?

Comment: Suppose `foo.o` depende on `buildtype.h`. If `buildtype.h` already exists and contains "1", and you run `make BUILDTYPE=1`, should it rebuild `foo.o`? If `buildtype.h` contains "2" and you run `make BUILDTYPE=2`, should it rebuild anything?

Comment: Actually the rule for buildtype.h essentially creates tmp file and if its contents are different then it will overwrite the file. I updated the code. I need to ensure that this process won't be repeated 1000 times for each cpp file and I want to ensure that this process will be done at least once. So, to answer your questions: it wouldn't rebuild anything when there is no need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to ensure that this process won't be repeated 1000 times for each cpp file

You shouldn't need to do anything special to ensure that. Make will keep track of the targets it has updated. It will not rerun the rule multiple times just because multiple other targets depend on its output.

> and I want to ensure that this process will be done at least once

The canonical way to do that is:

```
.PHONY: force
buildtype.h: force
```

You didn't ask for it, but a simple way to implement

> ```
> //pseudo code:
> if(TMPFILE != buildtype.h)
>     cat TMPFILE > buildtype.h
> ```

is

```
cmp -s TMPFILE buildtype.h || cp TMPFILE buildtype.h
```

**Update:** A related "interesting problem" is how to ensure that `buildtype.h` is up to date before any compilation tries to use it. Automatic dependency tracking systems can fail here for "clean" builds, because their output is only based on what header files they can see on disk; If `buildtype.h` hasn't yet been created, `makedepend` or `gcc -M` cannot know about it, so cannot generate correct dependencies.

One solution for that is to carefully hand-code the right dependencies into the makefile, like

```
foo.o: buildtype.h # because foo.c includes buildtype.h
```

A more foolproof but hacky alternative is to write

```
Makefile: buildtype.h
```

which ensures that `make` will update `buildtype.h` before it does *anything* else (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html)). So now `buildtype.h` will never be missing or out of date.

One disadvantage of that method is that even typing something like `make clean` will cause `buildtype.h` to be updated, even though it's not needed at all in that case. That can be mitigated for specific cases by really ugly hackery like

```
ifneq (clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
Makefile: buildtype.h
endif
```

Comment: I use it as part of android makefiles that already add all kinds of dependencies automatically to my makefiles. So, will this approach work (e.g. there is that .PHONY directive somewhere else auto-generated)

Comment: I don't know android, but multiple ".PHONY"s, even for the same target, are no problem.

Comment: It kind of works partially. It does not work with a clean project (when there are no dependency info generated, which is generated along with compilation using -MDD). In other words, with a clean project make doesn't know that to compile a c/cpp file rule `force` is a prerequisite. I tried to add %.cpp: force but it doesn't seem to work. Any way to add a prerequisite to all source files?

Comment: Adding a `force` prerequisite to all source files would not be a good idea -- that would cause make to rebuild everything always. Maybe what you actually want is to add "buildtype.h" as a prerequisite to your source file compilation rule?

Comment: Not at all. Force means that the rule `force` has to be run before anything is built. That's all. After `force` is run, regular rules apply.

Comment: That's not correct. You may want to read https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Force-Targets.html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643838/how-to-force-make-to-always-rebuild-a-file

Comment: Maybe I missed something. I actually add force phony target as a prerequisite to the header file that the rule generates. So, the rule always runs to update the header file (and the rule updates it only if there are any changes, which in turn will trigger recompilation depending on the dependencies). The only problem is that I cannot add that prerequisite to cpp/c/o files because I use android build system.

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote is just wrong about %.cpp: ... I simply tried everything with android BS and it does not do anything at all. Even force prerequisite to all source files. They do something funky behind the scenes, so I'm limited at what I can do

Comment: I updated the answer with something that might help. Also, I just realised that "%.cpp: force" cannot workm, because the "cpp" files do not have a rule associated with them. What you really mean is "%.o: force".

Comment: The Makefile: thing seems to be something that might get me the expected result!! However, on android ndk it has to be spelled like this: `$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)):buildtype.h` since NDK doesn't use `Makefile`, but some other names for make files. I'll just need to test to see what I can do to ensure that it runs this rule only when I need to build and not when I do `make clean`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using sed:

```
deps = 
ifdef BUILDTYPE
old = $(shell sed -n 's/\#define *BUILDTYPE *\([0-9]*\)/\1/p' buildtype.h)
ifneq ($(BUILDTYPE),$(old))
deps := buildtype.h
endif
endif

all: $(deps)
  @echo $(deps)
```