BSD make errors out on my Makefile while GNU make mentions no problem
BSD make errors out on my Makefile while GNU make mentions no problem, and I would like to know if it is possible to make it compatible with it? Not that I plan on porting the program now, but I assume anything is possible in the future. Thank you.

The exact error produced:

bmake: don't know how to make .force_rebuild. Stop



My Makefile:
# Use the latest version of the compiler on Debian 12 OS, arm64 platform:
CXX=g++-12

# Use the official standard;
# Optimize for speed;
# Stop on all warnings;
# Do not include debug symbols:
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic -pedantic-errors

# The name of the resulting executable file:
APP_NAME=auto-fan-control

# The name of the C++ source code file:
SRC_FILE=$(APP_NAME).cpp

# Possibly not doing anything when using GNU make;
# You may see this for an explanation:
# https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#index-POSIX_002dconforming-mode_002c-setting
.POSIX:

# You may see this for an explanation:
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/70199176/1997354
# Force re-build work-around:
.PHONY: .force_rebuild
$(APP_NAME): .force_rebuild

$(APP_NAME): $(SRC_FILE)
    @printf '%s' 'Compiling...'
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(SRC_FILE) -o $(APP_NAME)
    @printf '%s\n' ' Done.'
    @strip -s $(APP_NAME)
    @printf '%s\n' 'Running program... '
    @./$(APP_NAME)


On my testing PC, my GNU make version is:
$ apt-cache policy make
make:
  Installed: 4.3-4.1build2
  Candidate: 4.3-4.1build2
  Version table:
 *** 4.3-4.1build2 500
        500 https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

And it builds my binary and runs it just fine:
$ learn-cpp 
/home/vlastimil/Development/cpp/rpi4-temperature-moninor--and-fan-control
$ make
Compiling... Done.
Running program... 
25.0°C


I doubt this Makefile succeeds in GNU make. The target .force_rebuild is missing as this is reported, and the both GNU make and BSD bmake fail. Add the target like in the referenced link in the Makefile.
.PHONY: .force_rebuild
.force_rebuild:

$(APP_NAME): .force_rebuild


Maybe bmake behaves normal in my case, but may you confirm this, I would appreciate it, thank you in advance: I need to run bmake auto-fan-control in order for the bmake to actually do anything. Is this expected and normal behavior?

@VlastimilBurián, possibly that's normal for bmake. It may be taking .PHONY or especially your newly-added .force_rebuild as the default target, especially if they appear before $(APP_NAME) as this answer shows.  Targets starting with a dot (.) and an uppercase letter are reserved by POSIX for implementation extensions, but not so those beginning with a dot and a lowercase letter.  I think GNU make nevertheless avoids choosing any target beginning with a dot as the default target, but bmake might stick closer to POSIX.  Try moving those two rules to the end.
