# Makefile doesn't rebuild the obj's when the CFLAGS are modified?

Tags: makefile

As we know that the binary depends on the obj's, and the obj's depends on the .c files ( assuming a C Project). Let's say, I have a env.mk file. This file has a flag like 'export NO_DISPLAY=YES'. In the main Makefile, I have the following.

```
ifeq ($(NO_DISPLAY),YES)
CFLAGS += -D__DISPLAY_DISABLE
endif
```

Obviously, env.mk is included in the main make file. whenever, I change the flag value 'NO_DISPLAY'. The makefile never rebuilts the executable again. However, the same works fine when the .o files are deleted. I understand that the reason behind it as it depends on the .c,.h files. The .c .h files are not modified, therefore makefile ignores to rebuild it. But, I would like makefile to rebuild the code if the CFLAGS value is changed. How can I do it? Please note, I don't want to delete the objs and rebuild it.

```
target_dbg: $(patsubst ./src/%.c,./obj_dbg/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c)) 
    @echo "Target main rule__dbg $(NPROCS)"
    $(CC) $(patsubst ./src/%.c,./obj_dbg/%.o,$(wildcard ./src/*.c)) $(LIBS) -o gif_dbg 

./obj_dbg/%.o: ./src/%.c ./include/*.h 
    @echo "I am called first..dbg"
    @mkdir -p ./obj_dbg
    #$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -E $<
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -DDEBUG -c $< -o $@
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make simply works by examining timestamps on files. You hardly want every build artefact to depend on your `Makefile` (at least not while actively developing it) but if you seriously want Make to handle this dependency, you could put the `CFLAGS` definition in a secondary file `buildflags.mk`, include it from the main `Makefile`, and make all object files depend on `buildflags.mk`.

I hardly think anybody would actually do this in practice, though. There will always be situations where the only way to be sure you get a clean build is to flush everything and start over. Make sure you have good and up-to-date `realclean` and/or `distclean` targets, and make sure you remember to use them when you make fundamental changes to your build infrastructure. Having a nightly build job (or similar) which starts the build from a completely clean slate -- e.g. by checking out a new copy into a temporary directory -- is also obviously a good idea.

Alternatively, or additionally, include a copy of the build flags as a static string in each object file, so you can verify them later, perhaps using a `--help` option or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `make`'s `-B` option to force a rebuild each time you change your `CFLAGS`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816400/1885037).