# Have to write a "force" target in a makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a (GNU) make file with two-levelled dependencies like this:

```
INP ?= main
DEPS ?= bibliography.bib
# md-->tex rule
%.tex: %.md $(DEPS)
    panzer  -o $@ $<

# tex-->pdf rule
%.pdf: %.tex
    latexmk $<

.PHONY: show 
show: $(INP).pdf
    showpdf $<
```

This works as expected: `make show` creates and displays a PDF from `main.md` (or any other markdown file I specify) *when the markdown file has changed* by invoking first the **md-->tex** rule, then the **tex-->pdf** and finally the **showpdf** rule.

Now I want to add a target `force` which triggers the rules **md-->tex**,  **tex-->pdf** and **showpdf** regardless of the state of `main.md`.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29773961/65889) I tried

```
force:
    rm $(INP).pdf
    make show
```

but this is not very elegant and rather fragile. - I suspect there must be a way to create a target inside the current make invocation to say:

> Pretend the dependencies for rule X (here `show`) is out of date and trigger everything accordingly.

What the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You most definitely want to just use the `-B` flag. `.phony` won't quite work in this case. You should try:

`force:
    make -B show`

That should invoke the `show` target with the flag and make everything rebuild itself appropriately.

[ Original Answer ]

You either declare that target to be `.phony`, or you pass the flag `-B` (which I believe should be shorthand for `--always-make`). This should have (gnu) make disregard all the timestamps and make everything. I prefer the `-B` flag myself.

Comment: For a phone target does **not** trigger the other rules. `-B` does, but it is not a target.