# Alias target names in Makefiles or alternative approach

Tags: makefile

I have a directory where I download some data from somewhere on which I want to perform some operations by a script. When said directory does not yet exists, I want `make` to automatically download the files, which I would also like to be able to initiate by running `make fetch`. However, I don't want the download process to be started everytime I run make for the other target.

My attempt so far:

```
.PHONY: fetch
fetch: data/www.example.org

foo.dat: | data/www.example.org
    somescript > foo.dat

data/www.example.org:
    wget --mirror --prefix-directory=data http://www.example.org
```

This has almost the desired effects, except for when I run `make fetch` it gives me:

```
$ make fetch
make: Nothing to be done for `fetch'.
```

I could, of course, simply copy the recipe of `data/www.example.org` to `fetch`, however as the recipe may get more complex in the future, I would like to avoid that kind of solution.

**EDIT:**

It seems kind of obvious in hindsight, but for some reason I didn't think of using variables. I think, my mind kept searching for some kind of "neater" way. But *that* does solve it for me, so thanks to [l0b0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/96588/l0b0) for pointing it out to me:

```
FETCH = wget --mirror --prefix-directory=data http://www.example.org

.PHONY: fetch
fetch:
    $(FETCH)

foo.dat: | data/www.example.org
    somescript > foo.dat

data/www.example.org:
    $(FETCH)
```

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How do you force a makefile to rebuild a target](https://stackoverflow.com/q/816370/96588).

Comment: Another method is to just combine the two rules: `fetch data/www.example.org:`