# Force source rebuild in R package

Tags: c++, r, makefile, package, rcpp

This is similar to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816400/3961092), except specialized to R packages. Since R uses its own custom build process, what is the correct way to force a rebuild using Rcpp?

(For reasons that I won't go into here, all of my C++ code is located outside /pkg/src, and is called via a simple wrapper function that never changes. For this reason, when the important code changes, R thinks nothing has changed and declares the dreaded `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding

> what is the correct way to force a rebuild using Rcpp

the obvious answer is to rebuild from source

```
R CMD INSTALL sourceTarballOfPackage_0.1.2.tar.gz
```

The question then becomes where to get the source: CRAN, GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, ... but we have helpers for that.

If your code is internal, then you just need to rebuild *the wrapper* calling it, and that is still in `src/` in the package.  That is no different then another R(cpp) package linking against external resources.

Comment: "you just need to rebuild the wrapper calling it" -- precisely! And what is the best way to do that? By default, `R CMD INSTALL` will not rebuild this if the timestamp has not changed.

Comment: My packages all have a script `cleanup` (which is standard-but-optional part) which blows away, _inter alia_, what remains from `configure` and `gcc` and ...   These things can be studied by looking at existing packages -- you have almost 10k to choose from!

Comment: In RStudio you also have a 'clean & rebuild' option.  Approximating the cleaning step, you can probably just do `rm src/*.{o,so,dylib}`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This led me to the `--preclean` flag, which seems like the easiest solution. (Incidentally, I haven't seen the use of `cleanup` scripts before but this sounds like a great idea in general. Would love to see some kind of description of how this works!)

Comment: I am not sure why you may this sound so difficult as [this is documented](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add the flag `--preclean` to `R CMD INSTALL`. In Rstudio, this flag can be added under Project Options -> Build Tools -> Build and reload - R CMD INSTALL additonal options.